# Connecting to azure using PHP and PHP file is in WebServer

Tags: php, azure

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

define('HOST','tcp:sahilpaudel.database.wondows.net:1433');
define('USER','sahilpaudel');
define('PASS','asd@ASD123');
define('DB','db_sahil');

try {
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= HOST ; Database = DB ", USER,PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die(var_dump($e));
}

?>
```

Here is my PHP code that is on my server.

It gives following error:

```
object(PDOException)#2 (8) {
    ["message":protected]=> string(21) "could not find driver"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=> int(0)
    ["file":protected]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php"
    ["line":protected]=> int(9)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(6) {
            ["file"]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php"
            ["line"]=> int(9)
            ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct"
            ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO"
            ["type"]=> string(2) "->"
            ["args"]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> string(36) "sqlsrv:Server= HOST ; Database = DB "
                [1]=> string(11) "sahilpaudel"
                [2]=> string(10) "mypassword"
            }
        }
    }
    ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
    ["errorInfo"]=> NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RiggsFolly said, the problem is in the "could not find driver".

You need to have a module pdo_mysql. Make the page with the phpinfo() and look for
pdo_mysql. If there is no such module, then it is the issue. If you have that module, then the problem should be somewhere among the steps done - use the official tutorial - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/

Just checked - it is working for me with the fresh new web app.

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The defined values are not being substituted into your connection string

Try this instead

```
<?php

    $HOST = 'tcp:sahilpaudel.database.wondows.net:1433';
    $USER = 'sahilpaudel';
    $PASS = 'asd@ASD123';
    $DB   = 'db_sahil';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=$HOST;Database=$DB", $USER,$PASS);
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die(var_dump($e));
    }

?>
```

If you are still getting this error

```
object(PDOException)#2 (8) 
{ ["message":protected]=> string(21) "could not find driver" 
  ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" 
  ["code":protected]=> int(0) 
  ["file":protected]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php" 
  ["line":protected]=> int(9) 
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { 
             [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php" 
  ["line"]=> int(9) 
  ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" 
  ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" 
  ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
  ["args"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(73)
```

Then the important thing in here is `"could not find driver"`

Have you activated/installed the PHP sqlsrv extension and installed the SQL Server PDO driver

Comment: Add the new error to your question like the first error

Comment: object(PDOException)#2 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(21) "could not find driver" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php" ["line":protected]=> int(9) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(45) "/home/u710342539/public_html/CloudConnect.php" ["line"]=> int(9) ["function"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(3) "PDO" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(73) the rest is same

Comment: I am hosting the page in Hostinger and there is pdo_mysql but still am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the issue occurs because your PHP runtime is missing extensions. To use PDO sqlsrv driver, you need to install the extension similar with `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll`.

You refer to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php for more info.
And you can also refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-php-simple-windows/ on Azure Official Site for the steps of getting started with SQLServer with PHP.

Meanwhile, if you own web service is not in Windows system, you need to install [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) for the connection to SQL Server.